# Windows 7 to read text aloud

Tags: windows-7

General question about Windows 7, is it possible to get Windows 7 to read text out loud?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, use the Narrator accessibility feature.

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/products/features/accessibility

Comment: Is there a way to get it to read emails from Outlook?

Comment: @sep332 - The Narrator should be able to read most applications.

Comment: OK it sort of works in the new Outlook 2013 I just got, but it doesn't work at all with Outlook 2007.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [Talking Clipboard](http://www.talkingclipboard.com/) for Windows 7.

> Talking Clipboard is a text to speech conversion software, that can
>   read, any type of document, whether ePub books, web pages (HTML), CHM,
>   PDF, MS Word, RTF, RSS feeds, scanned image documents, etc. using
>   natural sounding synthetic voices (SAPI 5 compliant) and can convert
>   them to MP3 or WAV audio files for your portable music player.

Comment: How do I get it?  Is this actually some software?  Looks like a blog.

Answer (score -1):

i'm using [**Cool Reader 2**](http://coolreader.org/e-index.htm), works fine with Windows 7 x86 (haven't tried with x64)

just load the text file into CR2 and hit **Enter** to toggle ReadAloud (TTS) on/off or **F2** export to MP3.

supported formats:  **TXT**, RTF, DOC, HTML and FB2 (even archived as RAR, ZIP, HA, ARJ or LHA)

CoolReader 2 is free and portable (doesn't require installation)